# How to disable eslint(prettier/prettier) single quotes error

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier

I have react-native code. I install ESLint. I use it but its show error.

While I use single quotes it show me error

> Replace `'react-native'` with `"react-native"` eslint(prettier/prettier)

And when I use double qoutes it show me another error

> String must use singlequote. eslint(quotes)

here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

What i want is, how to remove error messages about using single quotes? I prefer using single quotes instead double quotes.

Comment: You can read the details of the rule [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes#enforce-the-consistent-use-of-either-backticks-double-or-single-quotes-quotes) and how add your own configuration [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring)

Comment: @MinusFour thanks, but i'm still confused how to use it to my project

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In addition to **@Barmar** answer, you could also use prettier configuration on a `.eslintrc.js` file using the following, property:

```js
rules: {
    // ...
    'prettier/prettier': ['error', { singleQuote: true }]
  }
```

Answer (score 14):

In your ESLint configuration you want:

```
quotes: [2, "single"]
```

In you Pretty configuration you want:

```
single-quote: true
```

You should also be consistent in your use of quotes, so you should use single quotes in the second `import` line:

```
import App from './App';
```

Comment: Eslint configuration and pretty configuration, what file?

Comment: For eslint you put the settings at the top of the JS file. I'm not very familiar with prettier, check its documentation for where the config goes.

Comment: if for some reason you need to use both double and single quotes, just adding `singleQuote: true` in your `.prettierrc` or `.eslintrc.js` without the eslint `quotes: ["single"]` rule worked for me

Comment: adding `quotes: ["single"]` gives me this error: ` Configuration for rule "quotes" is invalid:
        Severity should be one of the following: 0 = off, 1 = warn, 2 = error (you passed '"single"').`

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal Corrected it. The first element is the severity level, then the quote style.

Answer (score 13):

The two answers here helped me get to the solution that worked for me. In my `.eslintrc` file, I added the following:

```
"rules": {
  "prettier/prettier": ["error", { "singleQuote": true }]
}
```

Comment: Same solution as accepted answer

Comment: It looks very similar, but the syntax of the code is different and where I had to save it (`.eslintrc` as opposed to `.eslintrc.js`). The answer above helped me figure out the solution, but it definitely wasn't a copy/paste solution. Was just hoping this might help speed up the process for some!

Answer (score 4):

None of the solutions worked for me so in my `.eslintrc.js` file, I replaced the following line:

```
extends: "@react-native-community",
```

With:

```
extends: ["@react-native-community", "prettier"],
```

This is what my `.eslintrc.js` file looks like now:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: ["@react-native-community", "prettier"],
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I needed to implement the changes suggest above AND press CMD + SHIFT + P and select "Reload Window" to reload VS Code for the changes to take effect.